# CGAffineTransform MakeScale resulting in black screen?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scale, cgaffinetransform

Trying to flip a UIImageView with scaling it to -1.0 but it results in a black screen.  Scaling with 1.0, 1.0 shows results as expected.

Here's my code:

```
UIImageView *vImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:finalImg];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
[vImg setTransform:transform];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick all-in-one solution exists in `UIImage`:

```
- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation;
```

with one of the `UIImageOrientation*Mirrored` orientations.

EDIT: IIRC the prepended translation is only required for low-level `drawRect` due to the different coordinates system, so the scale transform alone should be fine. Are you sure the bug doesn't lie elsewhere?